# How to open a file after vimgrep and :cw in vim

Tags: vim

I use `:vimgrep /word/gj ./**/*.php` to search a word in all files. Then I use `:cw` to see all the results. I use `j` and `k` to go through the results up and down. But I am not sure how to open a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just hit `<enter>` or double click on it.   See the full reference:

```
 :help quickfix
```